# cart.js:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') at getForm

Tags: javascript, properties, addeventlistener

[erorr addEventListerner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0QUy.png)
Hello everyone, i need help for my project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple ideas that might help you:

1. Make sure an element with the Id of `firstName` exists in your HTML document `<input id="firstName"/>`
2. In case your form is created dynamically, make sure that this script runs after the form and all its elements have been created